Woocomerce 7.5.3 custom fields
I'm trying to add a new custom field with WooCommerce.
// Function to add a new field to the checkout form
function add_custom_field_to_checkout( $checkout ) {
    echo '<div id="custom_field"><h2>' . __('My Field') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Enter something'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Example...'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field' ));

    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'add_custom_field_to_checkout' );

// Function to check if the field is not empty when submitting the form
function validate_my_field_at_checkout() {
    if ( ! $_POST['my_field'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please fill in my field.' ), 'error' );
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'validate_my_field_at_checkout');

// Function to save the value of the field in the order data
function save_custom_field_value_to_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['my_field'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['my_field'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_custom_field_value_to_order_meta' );


But it seems not to be working, and I have nothing in the debug log. What am I doing wrong?
Chnaged all default wp themes adding this code to all functions.php

You are certainly using new checkout Blocks which doesn't allow custom checkout fields, You need to switch back to Classic checkout (legacy shortcode)
